# Is it possible to enable global double spacing in pandoc for Markdown to RTF conversion?

Tags: markdown, rtf, pandoc

I have a very simple markdown text file, and I can easily convert it to RTF using the following command line call:

```
pandoc foo.md -o foo.rtf -s
```

Nothing fancy there. When I convert it to PDF (through LaTeX), I know that I can create a template like this

```
pandoc -D latex > mytemplate.txt
```

and then modify the template to include

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
```

in the preamble.

It seems though that in RTF, double spacing is a variable for each paragraph. I have tried to generate a template, as in LaTeX, and then modify it accordingly, but it seems there is no way to enable global double spacing. Moreover, there is no option in pandoc like the --reference-docx and --reference-odt, which let me provide a sample document and then import the styles.

I have also looked to the RTF writer code in pandoc, and found that the paragraph spacing seems to be fixed in code, although I am not completely sure.

Does anybody have any hint on how to solve this? Or should I forget about RTF and go ODT or DOCX?

**Update 2014-05-28:**

Based on Oliver's response, I have been looking at the documentation, but still there is something I cannot see clearly. It seems that in the Writer for RTF format (*Text.Pandoc.Writers.RTF*), the spacing for the paragraph is fixed by creating two closures (rtfPar and rtfCompact) with normal spacing and no spacing respectively:

```
-- | Default paragraph.
rtfPar :: Int       -- ^ block indent (in twips)
   -> Int       -- ^ first line indent (relative to block) (in twips)
   -> Alignment -- ^ alignment
   -> String    -- ^ string with content
   -> String
rtfPar = rtfParSpaced 180

-- | Compact paragraph (e.g. for compact list items).
rtfCompact ::  Int       -- ^ block indent (in twips)
       ->  Int       -- ^ first line indent (relative to block) (in twips)
       ->  Alignment -- ^ alignment
       ->  String    -- ^ string with content
       ->  String
rtfCompact = rtfParSpaced 0
```

Then, when traversing the JSON Pandoc document and visiting the *Para* block, these closures are used as-is:

```
blockToRTF indent alignment (Para lst) =
  rtfPar indent 0 alignment $ inlineListToRTF lst
```

Maybe I am missing something, but I cannot see how a filter could be used to change the JSON representation and then create double-spaced paragraphs if the writer is going to ignore everything related to spacing.

Comment: Don't have access to my box to look up the code I used till this evening, but basically you need to override the writer and do that transformation yourself so it's already rtf when the paragraph handler gets it. It's not v.nice, but works.

Comment: Ok. That's fine because it means I am not crazy ;). I thought I was missing out something, but now I see that my first impression about having to modify the writer code was true. I am going to mark your answer as valid, although I think for my purposes it is not worth to override the writer. Thank you, Oliver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it by adding a filter. If you know haskell, then you can extend pandoc directly that way, but if not, then I'd recommend using the python library ([here](https://github.com/jgm/pandocfilters)) - create a python script that modifies the json to insert the per-paragraph double spacing formatting on hitting a paragraph element.

You can then call it by adding `-F ./myfilter.py` into your invocation of pandoc.

The documentation for pandocfilters is... sparse, but if you look at the examples and at the end of the [pandocfilters.py](https://github.com/jgm/pandocfilters/blob/master/pandocfilters.py) file (for the selection of types you have availiable to work with) it shouldn't be too hard to get going.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I have been looking to the docs, and still quite confused. I have edited the question in order to describe what I found. In summary, I think that the RTF writer has the spacing value fixed.